# Clamping camera around the background of a scene in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

so I have a base game setup that can be found at the bitbucket link below:

[Game link](https://bitbucket.org/2016globalgamejam/myinsanityv2)

I'm currently having a hard time understanding how to translate the camera node in relation to the scene's layout.

The goal is to have the camera follow the player up until hitting a corner boundary defined by the size of the scene. In this particular test scenario setup, the scene is 1000x1000 in size with a camera scale of 1.

The code below is used to modify the position of the camera when a new position is set to follow the character:

```
    var cameraPosition: CGPoint {

        get {
            return CGPoint(x: camera!.position.x, y: camera!.position.y)
        }

        set {

            let cameraScale = CGFloat(1)
            let sceneScale = CGFloat(1)//CGFloat(1 - 0.44  + 0.05 /*possible rounding error adjustment*/)
//            let viewAspectRatio = CGRectGetWidth(view!.frame)/CGRectGetHeight(view!.frame)
            let newPositionValue = double2(x: Double(newValue.x * sceneScale), y: Double(newValue.y * sceneScale))

            let scaledSceneSize = CGSize(width: size.width * sceneScale , height: size.height * sceneScale)
////            scaledSceneSize.height = scaledSceneSize.height / viewAspectRatio

            let cameraSize = view!.bounds.size
            let scaledCameraSize = CGSize(width: cameraSize.width * cameraScale, height: cameraSize.height * cameraScale)


            let minX = 0//-scaledSceneSize.width * anchorPoint.x + scaledCameraSize.width / 2
            let minY = -219//-scaledSceneSize.height * anchorPoint.y + scaledCameraSize.height / 2

            let minValues = double2(x: Double(minX), y: Double(minY))

            let maxX = 0//(scaledSceneSize.width * anchorPoint.x - scaledCameraSize.width / 2) //size.width - cameraSize.width / 2
            let maxY = 219//(scaledSceneSize.height * anchorPoint.y - scaledCameraSize.height / 2) //- cameraSize.height / 2

            let maxValues = double2(x: Double(maxX), y: Double(maxY))

            let clampedPosition = clamp(newPositionValue, min: minValues, max: maxValues)


            camera!.position = CGPoint(x: (clampedPosition.x / Double(sceneScale)), y: (clampedPosition.y / Double(sceneScale)))
        }

    }
```

There are hardcore value that currently fit the required scene size, and I'm unsure how to get those results via the scale. The scale by default is:

```
/* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
```

Without the knowledge of knowing there's a translation in scale, by default, I would expect the boundaries to be 
largestSceneDimensionXValue - cameraSize.width/2
largestSceneDimensionYValue - cameraSize.height/2

As a high level example. Would anyone be able to assist me in getting this translation?

Overall the scene should look like the following in all corners: 
[image: goal]

VS having the black background overflow in the camera as such:

[image: anti goal]

Answer (score 4):

Applications like this are exactly what [`SKConstraint`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKConstraint_Ref/index.html) is for.

You can see a demo of this exact feature — constraining a camera so that it follows the player, but doesn't show too much empty space around the edge of the level — in the WWDC15 session [Deeper into GameplayKit with DemoBots](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-609/?time=447).* (The link there should jump to about 7:27 in the talk where discussion of this feature begins.)

The gist of what's in the video, with some snippets from the DemoBots sample code:

1. Use a *distance* constraint to keep the camera centered on the player (automatically, without having to set `camera.position` directly on every `update()`).

   ```
   // Constrain the camera to stay a constant distance of 0 points from the player node.
   let zeroRange = SKRange(constantValue: 0.0)
   let playerBotLocationConstraint = SKConstraint.distance(zeroRange, toNode: playerNode)
   ```
2. Use a *position* constraint to keep the camera *within a certain range* of the edge of the level. Calculate that range by taking the frame of the level and insetting that rect by the distance the camera should keep from the edge of the level.

   ```
   // get the scene size as scaled by `scaleMode = .AspectFill`
   let scaledSize = CGSize(width: size.width * camera.xScale, height: size.height * camera.yScale)

   // get the frame of the entire level contents
   let boardNode = childNodeWithName(WorldLayer.Board.nodePath)!
   let boardContentRect = boardNode.calculateAccumulatedFrame()

   // inset that frame from the edges of the level
   // inset by `scaledSize / 2 - 100` to show 100 pt of black around the level
   // (no need for `- 100` if you want zero padding)
   // use min() to make sure we don't inset too far if the level is small
   let xInset = min((scaledSize.width / 2) - 100.0, boardContentRect.width / 2)
   let yInset = min((scaledSize.height / 2) - 100.0, boardContentRect.height / 2)
   let insetContentRect = boardContentRect.insetBy(dx: xInset, dy: yInset)

   // use the corners of the inset as the X and Y range of a position constraint
   let xRange = SKRange(lowerLimit: insetContentRect.minX, upperLimit: insetContentRect.maxX)
   let yRange = SKRange(lowerLimit: insetContentRect.minY, upperLimit: insetContentRect.maxY)
   let levelEdgeConstraint = SKConstraint.positionX(xRange, y: yRange)
   levelEdgeConstraint.referenceNode = boardNode
   ```
3. Apply both constraints to your `SKCameraNode`.

   ```
   camera.constraints = [playerBotLocationConstraint, levelEdgeConstraint]
   ```

For a deeper look, [download Apple's DemoBots sample code project](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/DemoBots/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015179), which has a lot of comments and supporting code that I trimmed from the above snippets to keep this post from getting excessively long. Everything for the camera constraint is in `func setCameraConstraints()` in `LevelScene.swift`.

<sub>* Despite the session name, it's about a lot more than just GameplayKit... it shows how to leverage many the technologies introduced in iOS 8 / OS X 10.11 / Xcode 7 to build something resembling a full-scale game: App Thinning, new SpriteKit features, ReplayKit, and a lot more.</sub>

Comment: You're missing the point of the question, yes this is a prime application for a constraint but the general offset still need to be calculated and known which is what the above question is trying to get an answer to.

Comment: *If your level is large enough and the camera never scales or rotates, your inset can simply be half the width/height of the screen.* If your level is always smaller than the device screen, a constant half-screen-size inset from the level frame is all you need.

Comment: Those conditions don't apply to the sample application above and I need something that can scale with the camera.

Comment: I added a bit more about how DemoBots calculates its inset. If you're not using constraints, you can still use the inset math — just set the position of your camera directly after comparing its would-be position to the inset rect. (Using constraints is a lot simpler, though.)

Comment: This is actually the best explanation of demo bots I have found. Thank you!

Comment: Terrific! Thanks for this! Do you know if it's possible to apply an `SKConstraint` gradually rather than having it take effect all at once? [I made a separate question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49596001/4376309). @rickster

Answer (score 1):

I didn't use your code.  I made a sample project and got this working.

[image]

heres my code

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    let world = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "world.jpg")
    let player = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.greenColor(), size: CGSizeMake(10, 10))

    var cam: SKCameraNode!

    override init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(size: size)
        print(world.size)
        addChild(world)
        addChild(player)

        world.zPosition = 1
        player.zPosition = 2

        cam = SKCameraNode()
        self.camera = cam
        addChild(cam)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            player.position = location
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            player.position = location
        }
    }

    func clampCamera(){

        func clamp(inout input: CGFloat, num1: CGFloat, num2: CGFloat) {
            if input < num1 {
                input = num1
            }
            else if input > num2 {
                input = num2
            }
        }

        let lBoundary = -world.size.width/2 + size.width/2
        let rBoundary = world.size.width/2 - size.width/2
        let bBoundary = -world.size.height/2 + size.height/2
        let tBoundary = world.size.height/2 - size.height/2

        clamp(&camera!.position.x, num1: lBoundary, num2: rBoundary)
        clamp(&camera!.position.y, num1: bBoundary, num2: tBoundary)

    }

    override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
        camera!.position = player.position
        clampCamera()
    }
}
```

this is the same image i used as my "world"
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmDb9.jpg

Comment: This is very similar to my first approach which doesn't work when scaling the camera back and other conditions. The main reason I attached the code above is to reference the specific scenario. If you can get the above to work in the code posted in the repo, then it should be perfect but I'm 100% positive it won't. The camera scale should be .44, but I've normalized everything for figuring out where the values are coming from.

Comment: Noting the width of the scene does not match the width of the camera.

Comment: i played around with your code and its starting to become my own project lol..  theres really a lot going on there..

  if i were you i might start a new sample project adding in each element of complexity (cameraScale.. etc) one at a time until you can find a simpler way of solving the issue.

Comment: That's pretty much why the above has been normalized. Essentially the only things that need to be noted is, the cameraScale is at 1, the player position is what gets set to the initial cameraPosition, the scene is 1000x1000, and the cameraPosition needs to lock the values into the restrictive bounds of the 1000x1000 scene showing nothing beyond those points (regardless of camera scale).

Comment: Nothing else really effects that, and you can probably delete everything non related to the scene configuration and player components.

Comment: The only area needed to be touched is the cameraPosition above. And just to note further, the anchorPoint of the scene is 0.5, 0.5.

Comment: The min/max X & Y values are the end goal... it's mainly a question of how to get these. The hard coded values above are correct for the current configuration and will scale with the camera. maxY * 2 = cameraScale * 2 type of thing. The real question is why that value and how do you calculate it.