# How to stop a SKCameraNode at the edge of a scene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a SpriteKit scene where i have a background (SKSpriteNode) that is 2x the size of the scene frame.  I've added a camera that moves around as the user pans and pinches with their fingers.  I have the pinch to zoom and panning implemented, however, i need the camera to not move past the edges of the background node.

I have tried using a physics body and edge loop, but that did not work (unless i set it up wrong). Here is the code i currently have and some images to help convey the message.  Should i be moving the background node instead of the camera?

```
self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
self.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = SCENE_EDGE_CAT
self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

mCamera = self.childNode(withName: "camera") as! SKCameraNode
mCamera.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: mCamera.frame)
mCamera.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = self.SCENE_EDGE_CAT
mCamera.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = mCamera.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask

func panForTranslation(_ translation: CGPoint) {
    let position = mCamera.position
    let aNewPosition = CGPoint(x: position.x - translation.x, y: position.y - translation.y)
    mCamera?.position = aNewPosition
}
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first
    let positionInScene = touch?.location(in:self)
    let previousPosition = touch?.previousLocation(in:self)
    let translation = CGPoint(x: (positionInScene?.x)! - (previousPosition?.x)!, y: (positionInScene?.y)! - (previousPosition?.y)!)

    panForTranslation(translation)
    print(mCamera.position)
}
```

Scene (gray is background image, red is camera)
[image]

Pans over to this...

[image]

But i need it to stop at the edge...
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a few ways you can do this.

In Apples sample game DemoBots they use constraints for the camera to follow the player. However if the players gets near the edge of the screen the camera stops following him.

```
   /// Constrains the camera to follow the PlayerBot without approaching the scene edges.
private func setCameraConstraints() {
    // Don't try to set up camera constraints if we don't yet have a camera.
    guard let camera = camera else { return }

    // Constrain the camera to stay a constant distance of 0 points from the player node.
    let zeroRange = SKRange(constantValue: 0.0)
    let playerNode = playerBot.renderComponent.node
    let playerBotLocationConstraint = SKConstraint.distance(zeroRange, to: playerNode)

    /*
        Also constrain the camera to avoid it moving to the very edges of the scene.
        First, work out the scaled size of the scene. Its scaled height will always be
        the original height of the scene, but its scaled width will vary based on
        the window's current aspect ratio.
    */
    let scaledSize = CGSize(width: size.width * camera.xScale, height: size.height * camera.yScale)

    /*
        Find the root "board" node in the scene (the container node for
        the level's background tiles).
    */
    let boardNode = childNode(withName: WorldLayer.board.nodePath)!

    /*
        Calculate the accumulated frame of this node.
        The accumulated frame of a node is the outer bounds of all of the node's
        child nodes, i.e. the total size of the entire contents of the node.
        This gives us the bounding rectangle for the level's environment.
    */
    let boardContentRect = boardNode.calculateAccumulatedFrame()

    /*
        Work out how far within this rectangle to constrain the camera.
        We want to stop the camera when we get within 100pts of the edge of the screen,
        unless the level is so small that this inset would be outside of the level.
    */
    let xInset = min((scaledSize.width / 2) - 100.0, boardContentRect.width / 2)
    let yInset = min((scaledSize.height / 2) - 100.0, boardContentRect.height / 2)

    // Use these insets to create a smaller inset rectangle within which the camera must stay.
    let insetContentRect = boardContentRect.insetBy(dx: xInset, dy: yInset)

    // Define an `SKRange` for each of the x and y axes to stay within the inset rectangle.
    let xRange = SKRange(lowerLimit: insetContentRect.minX, upperLimit: insetContentRect.maxX)
    let yRange = SKRange(lowerLimit: insetContentRect.minY, upperLimit: insetContentRect.maxY)

    // Constrain the camera within the inset rectangle.
    let levelEdgeConstraint = SKConstraint.positionX(xRange, y: yRange)
    levelEdgeConstraint.referenceNode = boardNode

    /*
        Add both constraints to the camera. The scene edge constraint is added
        second, so that it takes precedence over following the `PlayerBot`.
        The result is that the camera will follow the player, unless this would mean
        moving too close to the edge of the level.
    */
    camera.constraints = [playerBotLocationConstraint, levelEdgeConstraint]
}
```

If you do not use constraints, which is what you seem to be doing, you will have to add a check manually to stop the camera from updating. Something along the lines of this pseudo code

```
  func panForTranslation(_ translation: CGPoint) {
     guard mCamera.position < ... else { return } // Check your corner position and exit early if camera moved to far

    ...

}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I will have to do the second option, but I have already started to try that and ran into an issue.  There is no "size" property of the camera node.  So I can get the position, but I have no way of knowing where the left and right edges are without knowing the width of the node.  Is there a work around for that?

Comment: The camera will be the same size as the scene. So just fetch the scene size  e.g let cameraSize = self.size

Comment: Even if I change the scale of the camera?  This is a map view, so user pinches to zoom and to do that I change the camera scale.

Comment: Than you probably need to play around with the camera xScale and yScale property. Maybe in your scenario constraints are your best bet.

Comment: I was able to make this work with constraints.  However since i resize the camera scale with a pinch to zoom, i had to make some changes and put this code into a function that i call every time the camera scale has changed.  Works great now.  Thank you sir!

Comment: Here is a very similar if not duplicate question as well, not sure how i didn't find it before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137563/clamping-camera-around-the-background-of-a-scene-in-spritekit

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup Would you be willing to share your final solution? I'm having the same issue and would like a working reference that isn't the Apple example.

Comment: @XBXSlagHeap This is what I did. Just put it into a function to call and reset the constraints when you scale the camera.